# Permissions & File Structure w/ nginx & multiple sites

Tags: security, nginx

I am using nginx for the first time as a long time Apache user.  I setup a Linode to test everything and to eventually port over my websites.

Previously I had `/home/user/www` (wwwroot)

I am looking at doing something similar with `/srv/www/domain/www` (wwwroot)

Rather than using `/srv/domain` (wwwroot), the reason is many of the sites are WordPress and one of the things I do for security is to move the config file one level above wwwroot and can't have multiple configuration files from multiple domains in the same top level folder.

Since I own all the sites, I wasn't going to create a user for each domain. My user is a member of www-data and was going to use 2770 for `www` and have `domain/www` for each new domain. `www` would be owned by group www-data.

Is this the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best way to do this is to copy the wp-config.php file into the parent directory but name it after the site it is related to. Then place a require_once() call to it inside the regular wp-config.php file.

`/var/www/site1.com/wp-config.php`
`/var/www/site1-config.php`

`/var/www/site2.com/wp-config.php`
`/var/www/site2-config.php`

Inside `/var/www/site1.com/wp-config.php` you would have the following code:

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/site1-config.php');
```

Inside `/var/www/site2.com/wp-config.php` you would have the following code:

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/site2-config.php');
```

You could even have a specific directory for them such as `/var/www/wp-configs` and place them all in there then `require_once('/var/www/wp-configs/siteX-config.php')` just so they don't clutter up the `/var/www` directory.